# Square root of a Hermitian operator exists

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

There are a lot of questions here about square root operators, but none of them addresses the basic question of existence, and I didn't find a very beefy section in Wikipedia talking about this, so I'll ask it here. Let $A$ be a bounded positive-semidefinite Hermitian operator on Hilbert space. The claim is that there exists a positive-semidefinite Hermitian operator $B$ such that $B\circ B=A$. I've got no idea how you would prove this. Any tips or references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $0 \le A \le I$ (which you can scale to get for a bounded $A$), then there are classical proofs out there to show that the following algorithm converges in the strong operator topology to $B$ such that $0 \le B$ and $B^{2}=A$:
$$
              B_{0}=0,\;\; B_{n+1}=B_{n}+\frac{1}{2}(A-B_{n}^{2}).
$$
There are some basic facts you need in the proof, and these are not straightforward. First if $A$ and $B$ are bounded, commuting, selfadjoint operators, then $0 \le A \le B$ implies $A^{2} \le B^{2}$--this inequality is important in order to make sure that $\{ B_{n}\}$ is an operator monotone sequence, a proof which reduces to showing that the following is positive:
$$
         B_{n+2}-B_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(I-B_{n})^{2}-\frac{1}{2}(I-B_{n+1})^{2}.
$$
Then, you need to know that, because $0 \le B_{1} \le B_{2} \le B_{3}\le \cdots \le I$, the limit $\lim_{n}B_{n}x=x$ exists for all $x \in X$. You end up with a unique $0 \le B \le I$ such that $B^{2}=A$, and such that $B$ commutes with every bounded operator which commutes with $A$.

**Convergence**: I'm assuming the underlying Hilbert space is complex. The argument for convergence is not terribly long; so I'll give you that part. The only basic proof I know for the fact that $0 \le A \le B \implies A^{2} \le B^{2}$ for commuting $A$, $B$ is too long.

Once you have $0 \le B_{1} \le B_{3} \le B_{3} \le \cdots \le I$, then $\lim_{n}(B_{n}x,x)$ exists for all $x$ because $\{ (B_{n}x,x)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a bounded, non-decreasing sequence of real numbers for each fixed $x$. By the Polarization Identity,
$b(x,y)=\lim_{n}(B_{n}x,y)$ also exists for all $x,y$. $b$ is sesquilinear and symmetric with $0 \le b(x,x) =\lim_{n}(B_{n}x,x) \le \|x\|^{2}$. So $|b(x,y)|\le \|x\|\|y\|$ also holds.

By the Lax-Milgram theorem there is a unique $0 \le B=B^{\star} \le I$ such that $b(x,y)=(Bx,y)$. And, $0 \le B_{n} \le B \le I$ for all $n$. Because $(x,y)_{n}=((B-B_{n})x,y)$ has the properties of an inner-product, except possibly for positive definiteness, then the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds:
$$
          |(x,y)_{n}|^{2} \le (x,x)_{n}(y,y)_{n} \le (x,x)_{n}(y,y)
$$
Now, let $y=(B-B_{n})x$ to obtain
$$
                \|(B-B_{n})x\|^{2} \le ((B-B_{n})x,x).
$$
Therefore $\lim_{n}\|(B-B_{n})x\|=0$ for all $x$ because $\lim_{n}((B-B_{x})x,x)=0$.

Comment: Is this a pointwise limit of functions? I think this is the approach I'm going to use, since it requires the least external machinery. The statement about the square function being monotone follows from $A^2-B^2=(A-B)(A+B)$ (because $A,B$ commute) and the related easy fact $0\le A,B\to0\le AB$, right? The last piece would seem to be some kind of analog to the monotone convergence theorem, but since operators have so many degrees of freedom, I don't see *a priori* why $B_n\le B_{n+1}\le I$ would imply that the $B_n$s converge.

Comment: Also, does "converges in the strong operator topology" just mean "converges uniformly on the unit ball"?

Comment: What you state is the uniform operator topology. I mean that $\lim_{n}B_{n}x=Bx$ exists for each vector $x$ in the Hilbert space $X$; that's the strong topology. I don't think you'll necessary get uniform convergence. What is interesting is that $(B_{n}x,x)$ is non-decreasing in $n$ for each fixed $x$, with $(B_{x}x,x)\le \|x\|^{2}$ is enough to guarantee that $\lim_{n}B_{n}x=Bx$ exists for each $x$.

Comment: The reason $A^{2}-B^{2} \ge 0$ in this case is because $A$, $B$ commute and $A \ge B \ge 0$. You might expect such a result, but it's harder to prove than you would think. More explicitly, $0\le B_{n} \le B_{n+1}\le I$ implies $0\le (I-B_{n+1}) \le (I-B_{n})$ which then implies $(I-B_{n+1})^{2} \le (I-B_{n})^{2}$ and, thus, implies $B_{n+2}-B_{n+1} \ge 0$.

Comment: I added the convergence argument for you.

Comment: @Mario Carneiro: You mention that $0 \le A, B \implies 0 \le AB$ if $A$, $B$ commute. And you state that is an easy fact. I know of no easy proof without using $\sqrt{\cdot}$, which you're trying to prove. Other proofs are not so simple. Do you know of a good one?

Comment: I don't - it just looked like it wouldn't be hard to prove, but I'm not very familiar with the subject, so I'm probably mistaken. Anyway, thanks for your help. I'll put a link here if/when I ever finish the proof and submit it.

Comment: When you begin looking at all of the details, it seems to me to be easier to use the Laplace transform calculus. If you define $\mathscr{L}_{A}(f)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tA}f(t)\,dt$, then you can directly use Calculus to show that $\mathscr{L}_{A}(f)\mathscr{L}_{A}(g)=\mathscr{L}_{A}(f\star g)$, where $f\star g$ is the convolution of the functions $f$ and $g$ on $[0,\infty)$. That's why the power rule holds: the convolution property for Laplace transforms also holds. And you get something that works in a broader context.

Comment: This may well be the case; the main reason I'm not using calculus is because it hasn't yet been developed in Metamath (I'm working on that as well), and calculus on operators even further afield. But I've got to get to it all eventually, so I guess one way is as good as another.

Comment: I'm just offering some pros and cons of different methods so that you can choose. I mention the Laplace-type calculus because it's not very well-known; the other technique is much more common. I've been through both, and like each for different reasons. By the way, knowing how to get a positive square root gives you a way to prove the spectral theorem for bounded selfadjoint linear operators. So this is a worthwhile topic from my point of view.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Please in what references can I find your proof?

Comment: @Schüler : Bachmann and Narici *Functional Analysis* . It's a great text, verbose and clear.

Answer (score 4):

The Spectral Theorem is one way to do it. But it is like too strong a result: the ST gives you a Borel functional calculus, when all you need here is continuous functional calculus. The latter is achieved via the Gelfand Transform, that shows the isomorphism between C$^*(A) $ and $C(\sigma(A)) $; this way, $f(A) $ makes sense for all continuous functions on $\sigma(A) $, in particular $f(t)=t^{1/2} $.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, doesn't this mean I can drop the assumption of $A$ being bounded? That doesn't sound right. What exactly is the set $C^*(A)$ here? The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand_representation) seems to be working in an even more abstract setting than I am, so I'm getting a bit confused. Are the elements of $C^*(A)$ functions from $L(H,\Bbb C)$ (linear functions on $H$) to $\Bbb C$?

Comment: This is all about bounded opearators; with unbounded operators you have domain issues, so algebraic considerations don't usually play a big role. $C^*(A)$ is the C$^*$-algebra generated by $A$ (that is, the norm closure of the set all complex polynomials on $A$, although this is probably not a useful point of view). Note also that $A$ is bounded, $\sigma(A)$ is compact, so any continuous function on $\sigma(A)$ is bounded.

Comment: After unpacking the definitions, I get the statement that if $p_n(x)\to\sqrt x$ is a sequence of polynomials uniformly convergent on $[0,|A|]$, the corresponding operators $p_n(A)$ converge to an operator $\sqrt A$ with the desired properties. That statement, if true, seems a lot simpler than what I have got so far, since I don't need Weierstrass approximation or algebra definitions and what have you, and that makes my job a lot easier. (This seems to be a common tactic in math - bury the proof in a mountain of definitions so that the statement is nice but the proof is obfuscated.)

Comment: And would you look at that... the sequence $p_{n+1}(x)=p_n(x)+\frac12(x-p_n^2(x))$ is uniformly convergent to $\sqrt x$ on $[0,1]$. I guess that's where that sequence came from.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the general Spectral Theorem. You obtain

$$ A = \int \lambda \, dE(\lambda),$$
where $dE(\lambda)$ is the spectral measure. Since $A$ is positive semidefinite, you can show that its spectral measure is supported on the nonnegative real line. Then it is well-defined to choose

$$ B = \int \sqrt{\lambda} \, dE(\lambda) $$

Comment: Oh dang. That suddenly seems a lot scarier than the original statement, because I am now faced with proving the spectral theorem (which I don't yet have available) and at least a little measure theory. How would you state the spectral theorem without using integral notation? I'm hoping to write this as a limit of an operator sequence, but the integral is hiding a lot of complexity, I think. (+1 anyway, though)

Comment: Yeah, the general spectral theorem is quite powerful and I cannot say myself that I could prove it off the top of my head. Yes, one can represent the integral as the limit of a Cauchy sequence of operator-valued simple functions (with respect to the operator norm), similar to the formulation of the Lebesgue integral. What is the context in which you want to prove this theorem? Perhaps you can use more specific tools. Because I think the general existence of square roots does require the spectral theorem, more or less.

Comment: I'm trying to finish the formal proof started [here](http://us.metamath.org/mpegif/opsqrlem1.html). I am working in a very general context, and I agree that it will probably need either the general spectral theorem or a version of it tailored for this proof. I don't have the book, but apparently this is Theorem 9.4-2 of Kreyszig p. 476, according to the comment. The linked proof appears to be trying to show that the sequence $$B_0=0,\quad B_{n+1}=B_n+\frac12(A-B_n^2)$$ converges to $B=\sqrt A$, but the proof was never completed. Do you have any idea as to how this would work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know how to real formal proofs...what does hypothesis 1.5 say?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro if you can somehow prove that converges (I'm a bit tired and don't see right away why it would) then you can pass through the limit i.e. $$ B_{n+1} = B_n + \frac{1}{2} ( A - B_n^2 ) \to B = B + \frac{1}{2} ( A - B^2 ) \implies B^2 = A $$

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I linked to the first lemma (there are 6 available on the site, and a few more incomplete lemmas in the source code), which proves that if there exists a square root of $R$ where $R=T/||T||$, then $T$ itself has a square root. Thus it is sufficient to prove existence of square root for operators $0\le R\le I$. Hypothesis 1.5 says that $R$ has a hermitian square root $u$ such that $0\le u$, i.e. $u$ is positive-semidefinite.

Answer (score 1):

There is a classical way to do what you want if $0 < \delta I \le A \in \mathcal{L}(X)$ for some $\delta > 0$, and this may be more interesting to you. The approach uses the well-defined series $e^{-tA}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(-tA)^{n}$. The Laplace transform of $t^{-1+\alpha}$ for $0 < \alpha < \infty$ is
$$
       \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ts}t^{-1+\alpha}\,dt
    = s^{-\alpha}\int_{0}e^{-(ts)}(ts)^{-1+\alpha}d(ts)
    =\frac{1}{s^{\alpha}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{-1+\alpha}\,du=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{s^{\alpha}}.
$$
It turns out
$$
    A^{-\alpha} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tA}t^{-1+\alpha}\,dt,
     \;\;\; 0 < \alpha < \infty.
$$
and there's no problem defining the integral on the right because $\|e^{-tA}\|\le e^{-t\delta}$. Using classical methods of Laplace transforms, one can show that
$$
       A^{-\alpha}|_{\alpha=1}=A^{-1},\;\;\; A^{-\alpha}A^{-\beta}=A^{-\alpha-\beta}, \;\; \alpha,\beta > 0.
$$
The very form of the integral shows you that $A^{-\alpha} \ge 0$, and that $A^{-\alpha}$ commutes with $A$. Then you can get $\sqrt{A}=AA^{-1/2}$.

By the way, this approach works for a broad class of operators on a Banach space, which goes beyond what you can do with the Spectral Theorem. This is part of $C^{0}$ semigroup theory, where one can define $T(t)$ for $t \ge 0$ such that $T(t)T(s)=T(t+s)$, $T(0)=I$ and $\frac{d}{dt}T(t)x=-Ax$ for all $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ under well-known conditions on a densely-defined closed linear operator $A$ on a Banach space.

Final note: If $A$ is not positive definite, but only positive, then you can take a limit
$$
         \sqrt{A}x=\lim_{\epsilon\downarrow 0}(\epsilon I + A)(\epsilon I+A)^{-1/2}x.
$$
Using the above, you can show this limit will exist.

Comment: So you're saying that there is a square root not only for bounded linear operators, but also bounded-below (away from zero) operators?

Comment: If $-A$ is the generator of a bounded $C^{0}$ semigroup $T(t)$, then $T'(t)x=-AT(t)x$ for all $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$. And, for $\Re \lambda > 0$, $e^{-\lambda t}T(t)$ is a $C^{0}$ semigroup with generator $-(A+\lambda I)$ that can be used to defined $(A+\lambda I)^{-r}$. This $T(t)$ can serve in the same role as $e^{-t(A+\lambda I)}$ for $A = A^{\star} \ge 0$. Using that, $(A+\lambda I)^{r}=(A+\lambda I)(A+\lambda I)^{-(1-r)}$ will define the operator for $1 > r > 0$.