# Representations of Self Adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Consider this question asked in my mid term exam:

> Let H be a Hilbert space. Show that if $T\in L(H)$  is self-adjoint, then T can be written uniquely in the form T=B-A , where A and B are +ve and $AB=BA=0.$

Attempt: I am not sure which result to use to prove that T can be written uniquely in the form of T=B-A.

To prove uniqueness , I let that T can be written as both B- A and B'- A' where A and B are positive in the hope of proving that B=B' and A=A' but I got struck on this as well.

So, can you please help me with this question?

Thanks!

Comment: This is easy when $T$ is a diagonal matrix. This solves the case $H = \mathbb{R}^n$, due to the spectral theorem. In infinite dimensions there is also a spectral theorem.

Comment: What things have you learned about square roots and positive operators.

Comment: @Mason Unfortunately, spectral theorem is not covered in my notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning uniqueness no spectral theorem is needed. Assume
$ AB=A'B'=0$ and
$$T=A-B=A'-B'\quad (*)$$
Then $BA=B'A'=0$ and
$$T^2=(A+B)^2=(A'+B')^2$$
In view of the uniqueness [(see this)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545368/why-is-square-root-of-hermitian-operator-on-hilbert-space-unique) we obtain $A+B=A'+B'.$ Now $(*)$ implies $A=A'$ and $B=B'.$

The existence requires the knowledge of the [square root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814720/square-root-of-a-hermitian-operator-exists) of a nonnegative operator (no spectral theory needed). Then we define $|T|=(T^2)^{1/2}$ and
$$A={1\over 2}(T+|T|),\quad B={1\over 2}(|T|-T)$$

Comment: Hi! Can you please tell how using the 1st two lines you wrote $BA= B' A'=0$?

Comment: $0=(AB)^*=B^*A^*=BA.$